# How can I add the header to a text file?

Tags: powershell-2.0

How can I add the header to a top of text file using PowerShell? I have tried using the below code like:

```
Add-Content -Path E:\BHS_output_1.txt -Value (Get-Content "E:\header.txt")
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
$textfile   = 'E:\BHS_output_1.txt'
$headerfile = 'E:\header.txt'
$(Get-Content $headerfile; Get-Content $textfile) | Set-Content $textfile
```

Read the contents of header and text file after each other in a subexpression, then write the entire output back to the text file. The subexpression is required, so that reading from the text file is completed before writing starts, otherwise you'd get an access conflict.